# How to obtain MIN & MAX value of a Date Column for a given Month?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with the Date Column containing several entries of Date for any given Day. I would like to print MIN(DATE) and MAX(DATE) for each day for the month of October 2021. Is there a way to obtain the necessary results as expected?

```
2021-10-30 00:00:00.000
2021-10-30 12:13:00.000
2021-10-30 17:19:00.000
...
...
2021-10-31 00:10:00.000
2021-10-31 13:00:05.000
```

Comment: Please *tag* your specific RDBMS

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to get. What is your expected output.

Comment: Each day *is* a date, there's only one date per day - do you mean the min and max *time* ?

Comment: Without any futher specificationi of the dbms, I can just give you some hints. You have to extracte the date (ie without time of day) from your column, group by that date and select min and max from those groups

Comment: I am using snowflake. I mean the min and max time for each day is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following is what you are after - the syntax will vary slightly depending on your particular RDBMS

```
select Convert(date, col) TheDate, Min(col) minDate, Max(col) maxDate
from t
group by Convert(date, col)
```

**Edit**

The following should be a suitable port for Snowflake

```
select To_date(col) TheDate, Min(col) minDate, Max(col) maxDate
from t
group by To_date(col)
```

Comment: According to the Snowflake documentation you would use `To_date(col)`

Comment: @MaryoDavid Ok happy to amend and add above, I'm not familiar with Snowflake specifically but it should be what you are after.

Comment: Preumably from [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html) you would add `where month(col)=10 and year(col)=2021`